# Python Pandas - dataframe from Excel spreadsheet that includes hyperlinks to local files and folders

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains thousands of rows that represent 'sites'

One of the columns is named "Archive" and most of its cells, but not all, contain a relative hyperlink to a folder that's stored on my local machine

For example, a typical cell might have the following text displayed:

```
0130-0143
```

and contains an underlying hyperlink that points to:

```
Sites\London\0130-0143
```

So when you click the cell an Explorer window opens the archive folder for site number 0130-0143

I wish to import this spreadsheet into a dataframe `df = pd.read_excel('Sites.xlsx')`

and then export it again (after having updated the site list it with any new sites or changes)
`df.to_excel("Updated_Sites.xlsx", index=False)`

During the above process the new spreadsheet contains all the display text for the Archive column (0130-0143 and so on) but not the local hyperlinks

Is it even possible to include the local hyperlinks when creating a dataframe?

Comment: That might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325799/pandas-read-excel-with-hyperlink

Comment: I think you'll need to use xlwings or openpyxl not sure if pandas has the capability to this without adding on a bunch of custom functionality yourself! that said, if you find out post an answer, sounds like an interesting use-case

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction in regards to using the openpyxl module.  This code copies the target link from one sheet to another and also formats the cell        sheet_wb2.cell(row = j, column = 11).hyperlink = sheet_wb1.cell(row = i, column = 8).hyperlink.target
            sheet_wb2.cell(row = j, column = 11).value = sheet_wb1.cell(row = i, column = 8).value
            sheet_wb2.cell(row = j, column = 11).style = "Hyperlink"