# Extract hyperlink URL from excel sheet with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

How can I extract the URL of a Hyperlink in a cell in an excel sheet using python?
I have tried using Pandas and openly, but they didn't work...

below is the code I have written so far in openpyxl:

```py
    from openpyxl import load_workbook as load
    from openpyxl import Workbook

    file = 'tableCopy.xlsx'
    zipCode = 2110
    codeCol = 5
    linkCol = 6
    
    result = Workbook()
    rws = result.active
    
    wb1 = load(file)
    sheets = [wb1.sheetnames[x] for x in range(len(wb1.sheetnames) - 1)]
    
    for sheet in sheets:
        ws = wb1[sheet]

        for rowNumber in range(1, ws.max_row + 1):
        if ws.cell(row=rowNumber, column=codeCol).value == zipCode:
            rws.append((cell.value for cell in ws[rowNumber]))

            url = ws.cell(column=linkCol, row=rowNumber) # this is what i am using to get the url
            text = ws.cell(column=linkCol + 1, row=rowNumber)
            rws.cell(row=rowNumber, column=linkCol).value = '=HYPERLINK("' + str(url.value) + '","' + str(text.value) + '")'

    result.save(f'code{zipCode}.xlsx')
```

`file` is the file name

`zipCode` is the value i want to filter it with

`codeCol` is the column which has the zipCode

`linkCol` is the column with the Hyperlink

`rws` is a new worksheet(part of `result` workbook) and it will store the filtered data

i got the code for the `url` and `text` from the second answer here: [Pandas read_excel with Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325799/pandas-read-excel-with-hyperlink)

i ditched the `text` for now cuz its just showing the text of the next column

this is an example of what i got when i printed out the `url` variable: `=IF(COUNTBLANK(B107:D107)>0,"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(Setup!$B$5,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(B107,"+",C107,"+",D107,"+",E107)," ","+"),"/","%2F")),"Google Map"))` not the URL that i was hoping for which is a link to google maps.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Here use `openpyxl` module. First load the workbook (as an example first sheet):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('FILEPATH')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
```

And then you can use the `.hyperlink.target` of a cell. Put it in a try..except block, because if cell does not have a hyperlink then it will fail.

Comment: For some reason, it failed for me even though the cell had a hyperlink... and i got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'target'`

Comment: @PlutonianFairy if the Cell is generate via Formula, then openpyxl will not work.