# python/pandas read labels of hyperlink from excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel workbook with a multiple sheets. Out of these, in one sheet, a column is full of hyperlinks.
I want to read this particular column and get all the labels(text) without hyperlinks as text/list. I have a solution to get this text for single cell. But I am looking for full column operation. As shown in the image, all the ids here are associated with a **`hyperlink`**

[image].

I am using pandas,openpyxl. When I am reading this through `

```
data = pd.read_excel('info.xlsx', sheet_name='Data')
data[[data.columns[4]]]
```

,

> `output` : All ids (that have hyperlinks) values as `Nan`

Refer screenshot [image]

Could someone explain me why/how I can extract this particular column of text in an excel without hyperlinks and not ending up as `Nan`. Or where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_excel with Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325799/pandas-read-excel-with-hyperlink)

Comment: @DanailPetrov Nope. I am looking for a solution to extract whole column of Id's and not cell wise. That is the same which I mentioned saying I have solution for cell wise operation but not column as whole

Comment: can you please post some samples of the data?