# Reading an excel sheet containing hyperlinks using pythons pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, hyperlink

I made an excel sheet using pandas dataframe to generate texts with clickable urls using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'link':['=HYPERLINK("https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/","wikipidia")',
                           '=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com", "google")']})
df.to_excel('links.xlsx')
```

But currently i need to read the generated excel sheet (links.xlsx) using pandas.read_excel so i tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
excelDf=pd.read_excel('links.xlsx')
print(excelDf)
```

but this generates a dataframe with all zeroes in the link column.
Is there another way I can read the excel file i created, or another way to create an excel sheet containing clickable links on text using pandas dataframe that is readable?

Comment: The problem is that you are feeding the information as a hyperlink function. Can you do it any other way?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/65638445/13858953

Comment: do it as CSV instead of excel...  `to_csv`,  `read_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same as a csv which is cleaner (avoids excel issues).

```py
# %% write the date

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'link':['=HYPERLINK("https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/","wikipidia")',
                           '=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com", "google")']})
df.to_csv('F:\\links.xlsx')



# %%  read the data

import pandas as pd
excelDf=pd.read_csv('F:\\links.xlsx')
print(excelDf)
```

result:

```
   Unnamed: 0                                               link
0           0  =HYPERLINK("https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/","w...
1           1     =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com", "google")
```